# Default location opening/saving file

Tags: windows, explorer, documents

When trying to open/saving a file in a software
in the windows OS the default location chosen by the file explorer is the "my documents" folder. Is there an option to change this default location?
I do know that there is such an option For MS office, my question
is about changing generally these preferences.
Thanks in advance,
Amitai